# Coexisting spl_autoload_register and composer autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, spl

I got a legacy app which use `spl_autload` in order to load classes (they have no namespace)

```
<?php

spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php,.php');

set_include_path(
    $listOfDir
);

spl_autoload_register();

// require composer autoloader
// can't place that line before the call spl_autoload_register without breaking everything.
require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";
```

We recently introduced **composer** and Symfony `container`, `dependency-injection`  and `config` component.

What I try to achieve is to have camelcase class loaded via composer (all new classes use camel cases to identify new vs legacy code) without causing BC breaks.

**Do you have clues on how to get this working ? 
Do new classes must have a namespace ?**

PS: New classes will spread accross *"tons"* of folders. The project size is 700k LOC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So What I did is to put new class inside a `src/` folder, add a namespace and add `PSR-4` inside composer.json.

Because spl_autoload does not work with camelcase classes, i'm fine with that. :-)

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyNamespace\\NotLegacy\\": "src/"
    }
}
```